# server side pagination in ngx-datatable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, types

i need to add pagination in ionic ngx-datatable  using post Api

give me the sample of the code with full details

and sample of result.

after tried many times i didn't get exact solution for this.

this is the parameter of api
{
"ClientId": "name",
"Page":1,
"PerPageRows" : 5
}